# How to convert a CStringW into LPCWSTR?

Tags: c++, mfc

I have a function which retrieves resources from .rc file using CStringW.
I want use this returned value in sprintf_s.Is there any way?

//Snippet

```
sprintf_s(szMsgBoxText, LoadFromResource(IDS_INSTALLATION_COMPLETE),  g_szProductName);


CStringW LoadFromResource(int ID)
{
    CStringW m_resoucestring(MAKEINTRESOURCE(ID));
    return m_resoucestring;
}
```

sprintf_s giving me an error.Is there any alternative for this?

Comment: @MSalters: The proposed duplicate isn't. It's asking for **conversions** between ANSI and Unicode strings. This question is asking how to convert a Unicode `CStringW` to a pointer to its internal wide character buffer. No conversions involved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `CStringW::Format` which does exactly the same as `sprintf_s`. So your code will become:

```
CStringW sText;
sText.Format(LoadFromResource(IDS_INSTALLATION_COMPLETE), g_szProductName);
```

or even

```
CStringW sText;
sText.Format(IDS_INSTALLATION_COMPLETE, g_szProductName);
```

You can pass `CStringW` directly to any function that accepts `LPCWSTR` type of parameter as it has corresponding cast operator.